# How should I import another python file within a module

Tags: python, module, package, pip, pep8

I am building a relatively simple python module with 2 source python files.

The structure is like so:

```
├── MyModule
│   ├── MyModule
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── file1.py
│   │   ├── file2.py
│   ├── requirements.txt
│   ├── setup.py
```

inside of `__init__.py` I have

```
from .file1 import *
```

such that when imported I can simply type `mymodule.myFunction()`

and inside of file1.py I have

```
import file2
```

I then use `pip install -e .` to install the module.

However when I try to import it I get the following error:

```
----> 1 import file2
      2 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      3 import numpy as np
      4 import scipy.signal

ImportError: No module named 'file2'
```

What is the accepted way I am supposed to go about doing this?

Comment: You should be `import MyModule` and make sure path to MyModule inside PYTHONPATH or sys.path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the problem was that when the file is imported into the **init**.py file it sees the current python environment where it is being imported and therefore cannot see file2.py. However if I instead inside of init type

```
from .file2 import *
from .file1 import *
```

and inside of file1 type

```
import MyModule
```

then I can use functions defined inside file2 inside file1 like so

```
MyModule.FunctionFromfile2(...)
```

Another way of doing this would be to initialise a sub-package as discussed here https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/examples.html .

I ended up using it as a subpackage as that was more sensible for my particular case the directory structure is now like so:

```
├── MyModule
│   ├── MyModule
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── file1.py
│   │   ├──MySubModule
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │       ├── file2.py
│   ├── requirements.txt
│   ├── setup.py
```

Inside of the `__init__.py` in MyModule I import file1 as `from .file1 import *` and inside of the `__init__.py` inside of MySubModule I import file2 as `from .file2 import *`.

Inside of file1 I then use MySubModule like so:

```
import MyModule.MySubModule

MyModule.MySubModule.FunctionFromfile2(...)
```

This has the benefit of separating the namespaces of the functions/objects from file1 and file2 when imported as a module. As the user sees `MyModule.functionsFromfile1` and `MyModule.MySubModule.functionsFromfile2`.